# How to make my project easy to set up?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, automation, dependencies

For now, the repository of my application contains the Visual Studio 11 project files, my source and header files, library headers and their compiled *.lib files and some assets.

But it is a big effort to set up the project on every new platform to test compatibility or continue development. Each time I have to create a new project for the current IDE, and more important, download all the used third party libraries and compile the *.lib files for the current compiler.

Is there a way to automatedly fetch required libraries and compile them to *.lib files on all platforms? Moreover, it would be pleasant to cover project settings so that it is easier to set up projects for new compilers or IDEs.

Comment: there's a NuGet for C++ since some time, not sure if it works ok but seems worth a try for you?

Comment: @stijn Is NuGet cross platform or does it only work with Visual Studio under Windows? I visited the website and noticed that not all of my dependencies are included there.

Comment: can be used as a standalone executable, not sure if it works ion linux etc. This seems to indicate it works with Mono though: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/05/nuget25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, CMake (http://www.cmake.org/) is the best C++ has now. Like C++ itself, CMake is neither pretty nor simple to use, but, again, like C++, it's very powerful and versatile.

It's currently used by a great number of projects, which need custom and/or complex configuration and building.

Here's some of it's features, you may find useful:

1. It's not a build tool. It generates the files which will be used by the native build tools - Visual Studio solution files, GNU make files and what not. It supports a lot of compilers out-of-the box - namely, cl, gcc, clang. So, this addresses the 'IDE' part of your question.
2. It has a useful `find_package` macro that helps finding installed libraries to make use of it in the project. E.g. if you have the boost libraries installed, you can use something like the following code, which I believe is rather self-descriptive

   ```
   find_package( Boost COMPONENTS thread system)
   if(Boost_FOUND)
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
   endif(Boost_FOUND)
   ```
3. It has an ExternalProject extension, which can help automate downloading, building and installing libraries. E.g. for zlib, add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

   ```
   include(ExternalProject)
   ExternalProject_Add(
   ZLIB
   URL http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
   )
   ```

   It will fetch the tarball from the given url, build zlib, and install it. After that you can use find_package again.
4. In the end of the day, CMake is highly customizable. You can customize the ExternalProject_Add function to change downloading, building and installing rules. If it doesn't help either, you can always fallback to calling `curl` or `git clone` to fetch the sources, and call building and installing commands manually.

Once again, it's not an out-of-the-box or just-works solution, but it gets the job done, which is acknowledged by a quite large user base. To paraphrase the known quote, 'CMake is the worst build tool, but others are even worse'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sergei. For me the most important point is so handle external libraries, so that they get installed on any platform with the ease of a click. I could live with including everything in my repository, and every heard of using sub repositories for that. I already worked with Cmake, but as far as I know, it lacks automatic dependency resolution.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have it built-in. What you're asking for is something like a 'package manager'. Python has pip, Haskell has cabal, Ruby has bundler, etc. But I don't think there's such a thing for C++. I know at least 1 project with similar goals - ryppl, but I haven't really used it and don't think it has wide adoption. So, to repeat myself, you can get close to what you need with CMake with reasonable effort.

Comment: You gave me an example of how to detect installed libraries and use them. But my question is actually about the case that the libraries aren't already installed. This is because my project uses more than the commonly installed libraries. What do you think of including all the third party libraries in my repository? Or may I somehow use Linux repositories like apt-get on Windows to get the libraries source?

Comment: I've updated my answer a little. Please, see the new bullet on ExternalProject package. Also, I've changed the wording in the last bullet, to  make it more clear